# MADlib apply `cosine_similarity` on term frequency

Tags: postgresql, functions

I am working on a small topic modelling project and I have stumbled upon the idea of developing it in `MADlib` and `PostgreSQL`.

`MADlib` provides this [term frequency](https://madlib.apache.org/docs/latest/group__grp__text__utilities.html) function that converts my documents into, well term frequencies.

Are there any other utility functions that can help me to perform `madlib.cosine_similarity` or `madlib.dot_product`
 on the generated term frequencies which is essentially stored as sparse matrices (which is not a supported format for the cosine_similarity function that I needed)?

Comment: `to_tsvector()` is probably the closes to a "term frequency" you can get

Comment: No, I don't have any problem to compute the `term frequency` I am just looking for a more efficient way to calculate cosine distance on the computed data.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I don't think that Postgres has built-in TF-IDF functionality. I'd be **super happy** to learn that I'm wrong. Obviously, you can parse and roll your own counts.

In case you don't already know, there's a package that may be of interest to you called pg_similarity, here's one link:

https://salsa.debian.org/postgresql/pg-similarity

It's got a lot of measures. Many, including cosine similarity, can read data off of an index. The pg_similarity extension doesn't help you with storing or processing your corpus, but at least you get the math in a C function.

In a rare win for RDS, they've got this extension compiled and available. Otherwise, you need your own compile.

Here's hoping that you get a better informed answer...I'm just poking at the Postgres implementations of some of these tools myself.

Comment: Postgres don't have built-in TF-IDF functionality, the extension `MADlib` has TF functionality and a `cosine_similarity` function to perform the operation in C on vectors stored in Postgres. And I haven't come across pg_similarity surprisingly, it doesn't seem widely used but I will definitively give it a try.

Comment: I got it backwards, thanks for the reference. I'm checking out the MADlib project page now.